# Can't push to Heroku Push rejected

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, puma

I'm trying to push changes to my heroku app, but after a while it freezes and errors out. May be related with the fact that I was using puma for webserver but I had to remove because of incompatibility issues with plezi, the framework I'm using from websockets. My app in total is 4mb.

I get this error message:

```
remote:  !     Timed out compiling Ruby app (15 minutes) 
remote:  !     See https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/slug-compiler#time-limit
remote: 
remote: Verifying deploy....
remote: 
remote: !   Push rejected to my-app-3605.
remote: 
To https://git.heroku.com/my-app-3605.git
  ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/my-app-3605.git'
```

The setup I have with plezi, is that it creates a mini app within rails. It creates a folder, in my case `appname\` that contains it's own Gemfile, Procfile and appname.rb

```
|
|-- app\
|-- appname\
|-- bin\
.
. and so on
.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve the issue, it was needed to add to `Rakefile`

`require 'plezi/rake'`

This will solve Plezi/Rails incompatibility when pushing to Heroku

http://www.plezi.io/docs/rake

Answer (score 2):

As included in the response, the error is

> Timed out compiling Ruby app (15 minutes) 
>   remote:  !     See https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/slug-compiler#time-limit

You may want to check the referenced link and determine why it took more than 15 minutes to deploy the app.

Comment: but it seems to imply that the problem happens to big applications, but it has 4mb and not 300mb

Comment: It can even happen to a 3Kb application if you have an infinite loop that is triggered at compilation, or if you depend on external resources that caused an HTTP connection to hang forever.

Comment: I edited my question to provide extra context, because heroku documentation didn't provide me the answer, I'm using a plezi app within rails, it has it's own Gemfile, Procfile